# Parsing Flags in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to manually parse out arguments and flags given a string.

For example, if I have a string

`"--flag1 'this is the argument'"`

I am expecting to get back

`['--flag1', 'this is the argument']`

for any arbitrary number of flags in the string.

The difficulty I am having is determining how to process multi-word flag arguments.

For example, if I do (`parser` comes from `argparse`)

`parser.parse_args("--flag1 'this is the argument'".split())`

`"--flag1 'this is the argument'".split()"`

becomes

`['--flag1', "'this", 'is', 'the', "argument'"]`

which is not what I expect. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're in luck;  there *is* a simple way to do this.  Use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).  It should split the string as you want.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("--flag1 'this is the argument'")
['--flag1', 'this is the argument']
```

Comment: Python, batteries included... :-)

Comment: Most sizes anyway :-)